# dispatch_data_t conversion to nsstring

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement the PeerTalk framework in swift.
Getting this type when the mac is sending me data :

```
public class PTData : NSObject {
public var dispatchData: dispatch_data_t! { get }
public var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> { get }
public var length: Int { get }
```

}

One would assume that a simple conversion and `nil` check will do :

```
    if payload != nil {
      let databis = NSData(bytesNoCopy: payload.data, length: payload.length, freeWhenDone: false)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfDispatchData: payload.dispatchData)
        let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let strbis = NSString(data: databis, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("data is receive")
        print(str)
        print(strbis)
    }
```

payload being of type `PTData`! like stated before.
None of the methods i tried worked to get my string back, i get this :

> data is receive
>
> Optional()

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
let strbis = NSString(data: databis, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

return an optional type of `NSString?`

So you should write something like :

```
if payload != nil {
    let databis = NSData(bytesNoCopy: payload.data, length: payload.length, freeWhenDone: false)
    let data = NSData(contentsOfDispatchData: payload.dispatchData)
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let strbis = NSString(data: databis, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("data is receive")
    if str != nil {
        print(str!)
    }
    if strbis != nil {
        print(strbis!)
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not the optionnal here but the fact that the optionnal is empty, not nil but with no data inside of it actually.

Comment: Did you check the content of `payload.dispatchData` ?

Comment: Speaking of this, the really weird thing is that sometimes, if i print the data + the string, the string is displaying correctly ,i don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Well you need to explain me better if you want me to understand, did you check the content of `payload.dispatchData` or not ?

Comment: Yes i did, it's not nil and definitly not empty, i could print it